# TeeChartNet - valid license could not be granted for the type 'Steema.TeeChart.Chart'

Tags: c#, teechart

My company purchased TeeChartNet3 from Steema several years ago, we have been using the tool for Windows applications development since. Our IDE are Visual Studio 2005 & 2008 on XP. We begun migrating our application development platform from XP to Windows7 recently (using VS 2005 and VS 2008).

TeeChartNet was installed on our Windows 7 development machines without problems. However, when tried to compile one of the C# projects in VS 2005, an error message was triggered: "Exception occurred creating type 'Steema.TeeChart.TChart, Version=3.5.3188.18561, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9c8126276c77bdb7' System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: An instance of type 'Steema.TeeChart.Chart' was being created, and a valid license could not be granted for the type 'Steema.TeeChart.Chart'. Please, contact the manufacture of the component for more information.

We compared the installed TeeChartNet version number and the license.licx content between our XP and Windows7 machines and found they are identical.

With the error we are currently stuck with XP. Can someone help us to understand why the license error was triggered and how to clear the error?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Is your application being built with licenses.licx as an embedded resource? For further information I recommend you to read *Tutorial 17 - Designtime, Runtime and License Requirements*, specially the *Licensing setup for design and runtime* section. Tutorials can be found at TeeChart's program group.

To check whether the license is correctly compiled into your application you can modify the registry line in the machine where you compile the application:

*[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Steema Software\TeeChart.NET] 
"DesignKey"="Steema.TeeChart.TChart is a licensed component."*

invalidating it to:

*[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Steema Software\TeeChart.NET] 
"DesignKey"="xxxxSteema.TeeChart.TChart is a licensed component."*

If the design-time license has not been installed correctly on the development machine you can use TeeRegister tool, available at the client area, to make sure the design-time license is properly installed on your machine.